# Web container never contact database container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to use Docker to create containers for my web page and database connected to it.

The way I'm working is to create two different containers, one for the web and one for the database.

While both seems to work fine (the site is up and I've been, from the bash of the db container, in mariadb and the tables show up fine) it appears to me that the web page never even try to contact the database (I get nothing form the container log).
The situation is this:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  mrbs_db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: mrbs_db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: user
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mrbs
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: user
    networks:
      - mrbsNet
    volumes:
      - ./database/mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./database/mrbs_dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mrbs_dump.sql
    ports:
      - "33060:3306"
    ulimits:
      memlock: "1500000"
  mrbs:
    build: ./web/
    container_name: mrbs
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
      - "4430:443"
    networks:
      - mrbsNet
    depends_on:
      - mrbs_db

networks:
  mrbsNet:
    driver: bridge
```

When I run the containers there are no Warning or Errors.
One of my guess is that in the config of the mrbs code I'm using the wrong db_host or port:

```php
$dbsys = "mysqli";
$db_host = "127.0.0.1";
$db_port = 33060;
// Database name:
$db_database = "mrbs";
$db_login = "user";
$db_password = 'user';
```

I get also some error/warning in  the web page that might me helpful:

`Notice: Server failed to set locale to ["en.UTF-8","en-GB.UTF-8","en_GB.UTF-8"] for language tag 'en'. in /var/www/html/sale.lnl.infn.it/language.inc on line 174`

`ini_set(): Headers already sent. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time`

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`

Does anyone have any idea of what could be the problem? I'm turning crazyon that, I can't even understand anymore if the problem is about Docker or mrbs code.

Comment: You should change `db_host` to `mrbs_db` in your condfig. Do not use `127.0.0.1`

Comment: @AlexeyR. Thanks for the answe. Tried that, the output is still the same

Comment: port also has to be changed. see my answer

Comment: @AlexeyR. Yes yes, I did that in my try, but still no change

Comment: I just tried your set up (without volumes) and added `adminer` to the cluster as it shown here https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb and it managed to connect to your database. Are you sure your database started up without issues? Also are you sure that your config change has been applied?

Comment: @AlexeyR. yes, I'm sure the config change have been applied. I also made some test and with a simplier php app it works, so probabl it's mrbs fault. Thank you for the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running your compose with non-default Docker bridge network, Docker provides DNS for your services so that you can resolve hosts by their names.

In your case the host name of your dbms service would be `mrbs_db` (as your service named in compose file) so that your connection config would be

```
$db_host = "mrbs_db";
$db_port = 3306;
```

Comment: (Compose provides a network named `default` for you, and this will still work if you delete all of the `networks:` blocks in the entire file.)

Comment: you mean the network named after the folder containing compose file?

Comment: If you delete _all_ of the `networks:` blocks, Compose creates a network named `default`, and it attaches all of the containers to it.  Most practical Compose setups don't need to declare `networks:` at all.  Also see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.